# How to pass password containing a percent sign in jquery?

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

I have my client side validation for password not to allow characters like '?,!' but when i user tries a password with '%' character my client side validation gets passed in server side it fails. How to pass password containing a percent sign allowing the user to the percent character.

Comment: Disallowing characters in passwords is about the most ridiculous thing you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to allow passing % sign in URLs or query parameters being sent to your server.  `%` is part of an encoding scheme in URLs so it has to be escaped a certain way in order to actually send a `%` sign.  `encodeURIComponent()` will do that for you.

FYI, I don't know what this has to with jQuery or what it has to do with the regex you included in your question.  Your question would have made more sense if you include the lines of code that send the password to your server.  That's where the issue probably is.